# Populate DropDown with Array - AngularJS and C#

Tags: c#, html, angularjs

I have this piece of code:

```
$scope.GetEmp= function () {
    $http.get("/api/emp/GetEmps")
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.Emps= data;
            hideLoader();
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.operation_result = { result: false, Message: 'Unable to complete the action due to API problem' };
            $scope.show_result = true;
            hideLoader();
        });
};
```

That Method return this: 
[["1","Elmer Chacon"],["2","Juan Perez"],["3","Mauricio Lopez"]]

How can I populate a dropdown with this kind of data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selected">
    <option ng-repeat="item in data" value="{{item[0]}}" >{{item[1]}}</option>
  </select>
  <div>Selected: {{selected}}</div>
</div>
```

**Angular controller:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [["1","Elmer Chacon"],["2","Juan Perez"],["3","Mauricio Lopez"]];
}
```

You should load your data using your method, ofcourse.

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/jorisheus/69jv0ykm/1/

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Joris's answer but using ng-options you can do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item[0] as item[1] for item in data"></select>
  <div>Selected: {{selected}}</div>
</div>
```

**Angular controller:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [["1","Elmer Chacon"],["2","Juan Perez"],["3","Mauricio Lopez"]];
}
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/69jv0ykm/2/